# What words are used for Creator, Creation & Created in the Qu'ran?

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, creation

What are the most common words (Arabic & standard transliteration) in the Qu'ran used for *creation*, *creator* & *created*?

For info, in Yusuf Ali's translation: *Creator* is used 15 times,*creation* used 46 times and *created* used 145 times.

Comment: sorry at the time I have no time to search Quran extensively to answer you but these are among the words used as for creator, none of them being exactly the same: خالق، بارئ، فاطر and the words originated in them like خلاق. For creation: خلق، برئ، فطر. For creatures: مخلوق. Hope others will find the other words as well.

Comment: Thats enough for me to get started on. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Khalik" = Creator

"Khalaq" = Create

Creation = [Don't know](someone plz edit this)

It is Arabic, and it's grammar. Just rotate the vowels, new words are formed.

A related term, "Fatir" = Originator is sometimes used in the Qur'an to describe the creator.

May the creator guide us all.